# Line Counter In C

Tags: c

I am reading a book called C Programming Language 2nd Edition. There it teaches a program called character counting. But according to the output it does not.It just takes the character and does nothing.
This is the first version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main() {
    int c, nl;

    nl = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (c == '/n')
            ++nl;
    printf("%d\n", nl);
}
```

So when i type my sentence and press `Ctrl+Z` to satisfy EOF it gives me zero:

```
I am a good person
CTRL+Z
0

Press any key to return
```

It is supposed to count lines and being a beginner I could not understand.

Comment: Use `'\n'`, not `'/n'`.

Comment: Even with `\n` the program is not counting character, is counting **lines**

Comment: Just a side note, K&R is a good book but it is out of date and falls out of modern C standards. `main()` should be `int main()`

Comment: Also, it should be `CTRL+D` to put an EOF, and not `CTRL+Z`

Comment: to count the lines `nl` should start at 1, since 1 `'\n'` in the text means that there are 2 lines.

Comment: @DRC: not true; it depends on the OS in use (which is not mentioned).

Comment: @Jongware mh right I forgot windows has CTRL-Z for that

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help especially Powerswitch and Bathsheba

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the immediate problem is a simple case of replacing `'/n'` with `'\n'` (i.e. *escaping* `n` for the newline character which is what the backslash does), the fact that your code compiles and runs is due to the C99 standard:

> 6.4.4.4p10: "The value of an integer character constant containing more than one character (e.g., 'ab'), or containing a character or
>   escape sequence that does not map to a single-byte execution
>   character, is implementation-defined."

`'/n'` is a *character array* consisting of the forward slash and the letter `n`.

Once you've fixed that, you then will need to make changes to count characters as opposed to just newline characters.

Comment: Thanks it worked fine i put /n and not \n. So I changed it and it worked

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the implementation is supposed to count only the number of newline characters, not the number of total characters, as implemented in the `if(c=='\n')` condition. The program returns `0` on your input as it does not contain a newline character.

Answer (score 0):

might be that the program want to know if the next char **is not** an end of a line ( `'\n'`) so you'll need:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main() {
    int c, nl;

    nl = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (c != '\n')
            ++nl;
    printf("%d\n", nl);
}
```

this will count the number of **characters**, but there are others escape characters such as `'\t'` and so i'm not quite sure what the program is supposed to do, but i think that in your book you'll find some more description clarifying that part

for counting the number of lines simply change '/n' to '\n' as you probably know by now

Comment: it should count the number of lines.

Comment: @mch i was confused too because he said "There it teaches a program called character counting"

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you're missing a set of `{}` brackets:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
    int c, nl;

    nl = 0;
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {   // <- This starts the block to be repeated
        if (c == '\n')
        {   // <- This is just to keep the code 'safe' ...
            ++nl;
        }   // <- ... as is this
    }   // <- This ends the block to be repeated
    printf("The number of New Line characters entered was %d\n", nl);
}
```

Comment: that's not a problem here, both sets of brackets are not necessary for the functionality.

Comment: Converting C into LISP...? (Lost In Stupid Parentheses)